# to finish vs. to have finished

Tags: grammar

One of the rules of using the perfect infinitive says that it can refer to something that will be completed at a point in the future.

*We hope to have finished the building works by the end of March.*

I would like to know what would happen if I changed the sentence to:

*We hope to finish the building works by the end of March.*

Is there a different meaning? Is it grammatically OK?

Comment: 51 views, 3 answers, only 1 upvote so far.I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine grammatically but your alternative version changes the context.  "We hope to have finished by X" refers to the situation *after* completion, implying that there will then be other issues to consider - issues affected by the completion.  In contrast, "We hope to finish by X" only discusses the task itself, leaving open the possibility that you will have no involvement after X and will walk away.  It doesn't imply that, but it doesn't invoke any consideration of the post-completion context, unlike the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely grammatically fine.  There is, perhaps, a very tiny difference in meaning between them, in that for the first I would expect the building to be expected to be complete at the end of March (so that I could go in, walk around, complain about bare wires, etc.) while with the second I would accept that the building was still being worked on on the last day of March for the finishing touches.

It's a pretty subtle difference though, and I think it would be irrelevant in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues at hand concerning words such as *begin*, *start*, *end* and *finish*.

These are time delineation terms, or temporal boundaries.

Some languages that do not have tense inflection, use these words to define the tense of a predicate. Their use would naturally coincide and overlap with grammatical tense inflection.

2ndly, *finishing* a building is a construction term. Finishing could include painting, stucco, siding, trimming, etc.

Finishing could also include a lengthy administrative process of inspecting, qualifying and certifying the fitness of a building or structure.

3rdly, even if *finishing* is a momentary event, as far as humans are concerned, finishing still takes more than 5 seconds.

- I will finish eating at 5 pm tomorrow. At 5 pm, I will have the motivation to finish my eating.
- I will have finished eating at 5:15 pm tomorrow. At 5:15 pm, I would no longer have the motivation or the necessity for the motivation to finish eating, because I will have finished eating.